R - If cex value is zero, do not display plot in mapview
I'm trying to plot my results in a map by using cex to visualize the values of an object Imppar, however plots with values 0 still appear.
geoxy is a spatial object of coordinates of my plots and Imppar is a list of values (0-1) for those plots. Lets say following plots and Immpar values:
lon <- c(9.416733, 9.417530, 9.417697, 9.417286, 9.415672)

lat <- c(49.01361, 49.01647, 49.01470, 49.01703, 49.01494)

xy <- matrix(c(lon, lat), ncol = 2)

geoxy <- terra::vect(xy, crs = "EPSG:4326") 

Imppar <- c(0.1, 0, 0.6, 0, 0.9)

geoxy$Imppar <- Imppar

mapview::mapview(geoxy, cex = "Imppar", map.types = "Esri.WorldImagery")

I get this (every plot appears):

I'd like to get a mapview where plot 2 and 4, so plots with (Imppar) cex values 0 are not displayed.
I havent found anything to solve this for mapview. I could just remove the 0 of Imppar in the first place, however than I would have to always change the number of plots (as if not it plots the cex for the first plots and for the last ones the default). As I want to do this for a big dataset, this isnt viable.

I suppose you could swap $Imppar == 0 for NA and mapview::mapview(complete.cases(geoxy),
